# How to access values from the context:property-placeholder in MEL?

Tags: mule

can someone pls advise how to access values from a context:property-placeholder in MEL?
I've found an article that describes how to access the values from Java [here](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Access-properties-from-Java-code).
Need similar for MEL.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I had to find the answer by myself.
The syntax of accessing a property value in MEL depends on a type of the value.
For String values it should be like this:

```
MyStringVar='${MyProperty}';
```

while for numeric values the quotas not required.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple mostly same as in Spring container of java. You access it using ${key} where key is present in your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with ${propertyName}, where ever you want to access properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the property value as shown below:

```
<set-variable variableName="someName" value="${xyz.someProperty}" />
```

Comment: this is not MEL. But the question was about MEL.